# Functional Maximization

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization, calculus-of-variations, optimal-control

So how do we solve a problem like this:

Find the function $s(x)$ such that $s(x)$ maximizes 
$$\int_0^{s^{-1}(k)} s(x) dx $$
where  $x\in[0,10]$, $s(x)\in[0,1]$, and $k\in[0,1]$ ($k$ is a constant).

Thanks a lot guys. (So sry for my previous typos)

Comment: How can $x$ appear in both the integral and the upper limit? What is $g$? What space does $s$ lie in?

Comment: @copper.hat: Yea that's right, x is there in the limit of the integral. It's not a typo. I just add the characterization of g() in the question:)

Comment: Monoton increasing or decreasing?

Comment: increasing, sry for the confusion.

Comment: and it's strictly increasing actually

Comment: Then take $s(x) =1$ everywhere to get $g(1)$? I don't understand what you mean by making sure $x \in [0,10]$.

Comment: That's quite a change to the question. It invalidates all of the above.

Comment: @copper.hat Sry I was a bit confused. The problem should look like the one right now. I took it from a more complicated problem and that confused me. My bad.

Comment: Yea, and not sure if that's gonna be helpful: we can assume s(x) is strictly increasing if we need.

Comment: What do you mean by $x \in [0,10]$? $x$ is just a dummy variable of integration. Do you mean that the domain of $s$ is $[0,10]$? Also what do we do with $k$? For each function $s(x)$ do we take the maximal $k$?

Comment: @Soke: sry for the confusion. x∈[0,10] is just by its definition. It's like the domain of x is [0,10], and the limits of the integral are a subset of [0,10], which is already true since s(x)∈[0,1]. So I think we can simply ignore this extra condition. Also, for k, it's just a fixed constant, whose value is given. We don't choose k (and we CANNOT choose k since it's already fixed). Instead, we want to choose the optimal function s(x).

Comment: @larrybr So is $s$ also a function of $k$? Otherwise isn't that implicitly assuming that there is some function $s(x)$ for which every other function is lesser than it for every value of $k$?

Comment: @Soke: the inverse of s is a function of k. In other words, s(x) takes an x in 0 to 10 as its argument and maps it to a number between 0 and 1. For example, s(x)=0.1x, then s^(-1)(y)=10y. So if k=0.5, then s^(-1)(0.5)=5. For the same fixed k, different s^(-1) maps it to a different number in [0,10]. Does that make it clear?

Comment: Oh okay... though I'm still confused how it's possible to maximize this integral for $s$ when we're given a constant whose value we do not know. Surely the answer will be different if $k = 0$ versus if $k = 1$?

Comment: @Soke: Yea. I think the answer should depend on the k.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that, if $s(x)$ is strictly increasing then for $x$ between 0 and $s^{-1}(k)$, we have $0<s(x)<k$.

Therefore:
$$\int_0^{s^{-1}(k)}s(x)dx < \int_0^{s^{-1}(k)}kdx = k*s^{-1}(k) <= k*10$$

let $s_n(x)$, for $n\in\{1,2,..\}$ be a sequence of functions with:
$$s_n(x) = k+(x-10)/n$$

Then $\int_0^{s^{-1}(k)}s(x)dx$ goes to 10*k when n goes to infinity.

So we should say there is no such strictly increasing s(x). But we can say that sup of this integral should be 10*k.

Comment: this is my first time using this system. I didn't mean to provide an answer, I only meant to add a comment.